# Production-ready PayPal, 2CO and Authorize.Net libraries for Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, frameworks, e-commerce

Seems that Python lacks e-commerce solutions compared to PHP and C#. Any production-ready PayPal, 2CO and Authorize.Net libraries for Python/Django?

### EDIT:

1. http://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal
2. http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/969/
3. E-commerce: http://www.satchmoproject.com/
4. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/456361/
5. http://code.google.com/p/django-cart/
6. http://www.chickenwingsw.com/paypal-on-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might look into [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/)'s [source code](http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/src/).  Satchmo is an open source e-commerce app for Django, and I'm pretty sure that it has support for a variety of payment gateways.

Their [payment modules](http://bitbucket.org/chris1610/satchmo/src/tip/satchmo/apps/payment/modules/) appear to work with at least PayPal and Authorize.Net from the list you gave, among others.

Comment: The satchmo payment processing code is also being broken out into its own project.  http://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-bursar/